# Computer vision: Segmentation of XRay image vertebrae detection

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, aforge

I have struggling for past few weeks trying to implement vertabrae segmentation on an XRay image of head, my research has brought me to dead end.

What is the best method for accomplishing this?

I have searched around and my best guess would be AAM (Active Appearence Model) implemented on Active Shape Model but I cant find any literature or source code on how to implement this (accept in Matlab), it has been brought to my attention that with structure tensor I could find predominant directions on gradient and from that information extract the corners of vertabrae but math is confusing me a little bit.

If any body has any suggestions literature or source code (Java, C, C#, Python... [anything except matlab]), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with OpenCV (http://opencv.org/)

> OpenCV is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both
>   academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces
>   and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android. OpenCV was
>   designed for computational efficiency and with a strong focus on
>   real-time applications. Written in optimized C/C++, the library can
>   take advantage of multi-core processing. Adopted all around the world,
>   OpenCV has more than 47 thousand people of user community and
>   estimated number of downloads exceeding 6 million. Usage ranges from
>   interactive art, to mines inspection, stitching maps on the web or
>   through advanced robotics.

However the area you mention is a hard research area and there are no simple solutions. OpenCV has hundreds of high-quality routines and even finding your way around will take some time. The methods you use will probably depend on the quality, type, resolution, etc. of your images.

Comment: Hello Peter thenks for your input, I do understand that area is quite complex and I have problem that API's like OpenCV, hide many things are through abstraction layer I would mutch prefer some literature on how this is done, becouse I would like to get at least mental model that would help me a lot, this is not a production software that I'm building and it does not have to be implemented I just have to learn how this is done, again many thanks for your answer I will look around OpenCV seems like a good start.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place for wide-ranging domain-specific questions. If you had a limited question like "how do I do edge detection in OpenCV" that could work. I would find a specialist open group and make some contacts.

Comment: Sorry I was not aware of that, I see then I will go about browsing through OpenCV documentation and try to implement this and get back with some concrete questions, many thanks Peter :)